# Redux reducer prevState already set up to newState

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux to move search filter through application to components.

I have component where I set up filters and call dispatch function using

```
this.props.dispatch(setFilter(newFilter));
```

I use sliders / range components to set up values, those components have *`handleAfterChange`*   method which is set up to call mentioned dispatch function. This is working fine.

I have also filters that are set up by clicking buttons, I created `onClick` handler, and this handler call mentioned function. I checked what I am sending to `setFilter` functions (newFilter) parameter and it is what I want to set up.

My set action is defined:

```
export const setFilter = (filter = {}) => {
    return {
        type: SET_FILTER,
        filter
    };
};
```

My reducer is:

```
const searchFilter = (prevState = INITIAL_STATE.filter, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_FILTER: {
            // prevState is already the state 
            // I want to set up in this reducer
            console.log(prevState);
            return  Object.assign({}, prevState, action.filter);

        }
        case RESET_FILTER: {
            return INITIAL_STATE.filter;
        }
        default: {
            return prevState;
        }
    }
};
```

Problem is that prevState is already the object I want to set up in reducer. 
I am checking (in another component) if filter has been changed and because of that I get prevProps and nextProps the same so no action will be triggered.

So somehow dispatched changes are already in reducer as prevProps.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, most people call prevState simply state as it's the current state for that reducer. If it's already updated then you updated it, why don't you have a look at Redux tab (install if you don't have it) of Chrome devtools and see what is updating it?

Comment: I use redux logging tool where I can see information about redux transaction - prev state, action and next state. I do not know why the prev state is already the state that needs to be set up. I also installed Redux devTools into chrome as you suggested  and I can see there that only one action was triggered and diff of prevState and nextState is what I expect to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RIYAJKHAN was partially right.

Somehow I was modifying redux store directly, even if I made all object modifications via `Object.assign(...)`. 
In the end I had to create copy of object I was modifying - `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filter))` and then update this new object and dispatch it to redux store

Answer (score 0):

In `searchFilter` reducer,you are returning the `prevState` as it is without mutating.

```
return prevState    //which is reference to prevState = INITIAL_STATE.filter
```

correct way (no sure about state structure),

```
 default: {
        return {...prevState};
     }
```

OR

```
 return  Object.assign({}, prevState);
```

Comment: Yes, but it is in case when action type is not SET_FILTER or RESET_FILTER which is not this, case because it goes to the case where action.type is SET_FILTER

Comment: Initially your default case executed,So,reference is getting updated without reducers,Use above method for RESET_FILTER also.It will work

Comment: This is not true, if you do not need to modify the state then return it unmodified. Otherwise you will cause React to do unnecessary render reconciliation.

Comment: @DominicTobias agree but trick part is reference getting updated without action-disatach

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN you were partially right. Somehow I was modifying redux store directly, even if I made all object modifications via Object.assign(...). In the end I had to create copy of object I was modifying -  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filter)) and then update this new object and dispatch it to redux store.